# How to forward declare a method in C++/CLI to match the signature of a "Managed Extensions for C++" method which takes a reference to a managed type

Tags: c++-cli, cil, managed-c++

I'd like to call a method being compiled with `/clr:oldsyntax` (Managed Extensions for C++ syntax) from c++ code being compiled with `/clr` (C++/CLI). However, I'm having trouble forward declaring the method in C++/CLI such that it matches up to the "Managed Extensions for C++" signature.

The declaration in the version using "Managed Extensions for C++" looks like:

```
void MangToUnMangDateTime(System::DateTime & managedDT, tm& unmangDT);
```

*Note: The first parameter (managedDT) is the parameter of interest for this question.* This results in the following msil for the method (found using ildasm.exe):

```
.method assembly static void  MangToUnMangDateTime(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime& modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) managedDT,
                                                   valuetype tm* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) unmangDT) cil managed
```

### First Attempt:

My first attempt to forward declare this method in C++/CLI looked like:

```
void MangToUnMangDateTime2(System::DateTime % managedDT, tm& unmangDT);
```

which resulted in the following msil:

```
.method assembly static void  MangToUnMangDateTime(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime& managedDT,
                                                    valuetype tm* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) unmangDT) cil managed
```

which matches except for the additional modopt MSIL declarator included in the "Managed Extensions for C++" version:

```
modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced)
```

### Second Attempt

My second attempt to forward declare this method in C++/CLI looked like:

```
MangToUnMangDateTime(System::DateTime & managedDT, tm& unmangDT);
```

*As a side note, I was surpised this compiled in C++/CLI since I expected it to want me to use the % syntax on a managed type.*  This resulted in the following msil:

```
.method assembly static void  MangToUnMangDateTime(valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) managedDT,
                                                   valuetype tm* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) unmangDT) cil managed
```

This one matches the modopt MSIL declarator, but is a pointer `*` instead of a reference `&`.

### Question:

**So, is there a way for me to forward declare this in C++/CLI to match the signature in the "Managed Extensions for C++" version?** Perhaps via an attribute on the parameter?

**Constraints**: I do not want to modify the "Managed Extensions for C++" version.  Clearly, if I modify the "Managed Extensions for C++" version to be passed by value (which it probably should have been in the first place):

```
void MangToUnMangDateTime(System::DateTime managedDT, tm& unmangDT);
```

then I can get the signatures to match by using the same declaration in C++/CLI.

Comment: Stop forward-declaring types from another assembly.  Just add a reference to it.  This isn't C anymore, no need for header files.

Comment: @Hans: That doesn't make any sense--this isn't C#, it's C++/CLI so there are still header files.  This method is in the *same* assembly, it's just in another compilation unit. The header file for the one compilation unit is written in "Managed Extensions for C++" syntax (/clr:oldsyntax).  The compilation unit from which I want to call the method is in C++/CLI syntax (/clr).  Thus, I can't include the "Managed Extensions" header because compiling under /clr cannot understand the /clr:oldsyntax syntax.

Comment: They don't have to be in the same project.  Make 2 DLLs.

Comment: @Hans: I'll wait and see if I get an answer to my question instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be completely wrong, but shouldn't we consider the IL produced by "Managed Extensions for C++" broken in the first place ? Why would you add an `IsImplicitlyDereferenced` attribute to a  reference parameter ?

From this point of view, I guess it's an answer to state that you probably won't be able to produce the exact same signature with C++/CLI (but that's actually a good thing), and that your first attempt was indeed the correct way to go.

Comment: It could be considered "broken" or "obsolete", I suppose.  But, I was hoping there is at least a way for me to forward declare it and call it from the same assembly.  Maybe not, though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use ^ (`System::DateTime^`)- this declares a managed reference in C++/CLI. I don't know anything about /oldsyntax, but it takes a reference to a CLR type, so I'm thinking that this is the equivalent.

Comment: Ugh, no, DateTime is a value type.  The ^ should only be used for reference types.

Comment: That's not correct. That generates the following msil: .method assembly static void MangToUnMangDateTime(class [mscorlib]System.ValueType modopt([mscorlib]System.DateTime) modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsBoxed) managedDT, valuetype tm* modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsImplicitlyDereferenced) unmangDT) cil managed